# Implement show more button in table using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement show more button on the table with clients and theirs projects.
This is my code

```
<tbody className="text-gray-700">
  {clients.map((client, i) => (
    <tr key={i} className="border-b-2">
      <td className="pl-2">
        <div className="flex flex-col">
          <span className="ml-3 text-lg font-bold">{client.name} </span>
        </div>
      </td>

      <td className="text-center">
        {projects
          .filter((project) => project.client_id === client.id)
          .slice(0, numberOfItems)
          .map((filterProject, key) => (
            <div key={filterProject.id} className="text-left mb-1 w-2/3">
              <div className="cursor-pointer text-base">
                {filterProject.label}
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        <a
          className=" text-buttonColor float-left text-left cursor-pointer text-sm"
          onClick={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}
        >
          click for more
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

where

```
const [ showMore, setShowMore ] = useState(false)
const numberOfItems = showMore ? projects.length : 3
```

The problem is when I click on show more all projects of all clients are shown, and I need to show all projects of only one client which is clicked.
Anyone have idea how to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `showMore` state should hold the `id` of the client that you currently wish to expend, and `null` if none.

```
const [ showMore, setShowMore ] = useState(null)
```

Then you can slice the number of viewed projects for a client accordingly:

```
<td className="text-center">
  {projects
    .filter((project) => project.client_id === client.id)
    .slice(0, showMore === client.id ? projects.length : 3) // slice according to the selected id
    .map((filterProject, key) => (
      <div key={filterProject.id} className="text-left mb-1 w-2/3">
        <div className="cursor-pointer text-base">
          {filterProject.label}
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  <a
    className=" text-buttonColor float-left text-left cursor-pointer text-sm"
    onClick={() => setShowMore(showMore === null ? client.id : null)}  // set the currently expended item
  >
    click for more
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my day.... It's so simple and I like your idea

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to just change `showMore` to use numbers instead of true/false. Set it to -1 at the start and change it to the iterator of your map function:  `onClick = {(i)=>setShowMore(i)}`

Then all you have to do is check if `i === showMore` before showing more.

Just set it back to -1 when you want to remove whatever the more is that you are showing

Answer (score 0):

I write [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-resonance-464eo?file=/src/Clients.js) for your implementation